# Isotope is only working in one image container

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-isotope

For some reason JQuery Isotope is only working in one image container. Can anyone tell me why?

```
    <div id="container"><div>
        <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=77&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg"  width="200" height="126" />
    </div><div>
        <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=80&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg"  width="200" height="133" />
    </div></div>

    <div id="container"><div>
        <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=90&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg" title="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg" width="200" height="133" />
    </div><div>
        <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=92&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg" title="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg" width="200" height="126" />
    </div></div>

 <script>
  var $container = $('#container');
  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    animationEngine : 'jquery',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 350,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    },
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 203
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: i'm thinking now it is because maybe I should be using a unique container id... yes/no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're using two of the same IDs on one page.  IDs must be unique, and you must group all your items in one particular ID (which is `#container`) in order for isotope to apply to all `.item` nodes.  I've clarified the HTML to demonstrate this (this will make all four items interact with each other):

```
<div id="container">
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=77&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg"  width="200" height="126" />
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=80&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg"  width="200" height="133" />
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=90&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg" title="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg" width="200" height="133" />
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=92&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg" title="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg" width="200" height="126" />
</div>
```

---

Keep in mind isotope positions all your elements based on the `#container` width and height, so your chances of having `.item` in two separate IDs may not work well unless you explicitly declare both IDs.  Here's an example of having two separate isotope instances:

```
<div id="container">
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=77&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg"  width="200" height="126" />
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=80&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg"  width="200" height="133" />
</div

<div id="container2">
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=90&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg" title="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - blog130812_fish.jpg" width="200" height="133" />
    <img class="item" src="./download/file.php?id=92&amp;t=1" alt="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg" title="gh h gh gjgh h gjjh gk - 418635_486786424666755_551315440_n.jpg" width="200" height="126" />
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
  var $container = $('#container');
  var $container2 = $('#container2');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    animationEngine : 'jquery',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 350,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    },
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 203
    }
  });

  $container2.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    animationEngine : 'jquery',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 350,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    },
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 203
    }
  });
```

Good luck!

Comment: yes I thought this was the case only a few minutes after posting my question. Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @JizboJonez No problem, I'm glad you were able to catch it yourself.